# elliptic equation

Tags: differential-equations

How to prove that (2) is the fundamental solution (1)???

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(P\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(P\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial y}\right)=0$   (1)

$\Phi=-\varphi_0\ln r+f$   (2)

$\varphi_0$ - solution of (1) ($\varphi_0(M,N)=1$ if $M=N$)

$f$ - belongs $C^{(2)}$ ($f(M,N)=0$ if $M=N$)

$r=\sqrt{(x-\xi)^2+(y-\eta)^2}$, $M(x,y)$, $N(\xi,\eta)$

(1) - Elliptic Equations

P.S. always possible to allocate the logarithm of the fundamental solutions of elliptic type?

Comment: What is $P$ here?

Comment: $P=P(M)$, $M(x,y)$. 

as minimum $P\in C^(1)$.



Comment: sorry $C^{(1)}$

Comment: And what is $M$ and $N$? This question is not very clearly written in the state it is. But I suspect that it may be outside the scope of this website. (Please see the FAQ for what kinds of questions are generally asked here.) You may have better luck with http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: $M(x,y)$ - observation point

$N(\xi,\eta)$ - the location of  drain (singular point)